# use jquery to get data from group of submit buttons clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form that looks like the one attached, where a user will click a button to submit the form.  It needs to be a POST and not a GET.

[image]

My form looks like this:

```
<form ...>
<input type="hidden" name="planId" value="" id="planId">
<input type="submit" data-planid="N00BASIC1" name="select" value="Select" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-round" id="select">
<input type="submit" data-planid="N00BASIC3" name="select" value="Select" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-round" id="select">
<input type="submit" data-planid="N00BASIC6" name="select" value="Select" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-round" id="select">
<input type="submit" data-planid="N00BASIC112" name="select" value="Select" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-round" id="select">
</form>
```

I'm using jquery to submit the form.  Before the form is submitted i'm trying to pull out the data field for the planId the user selected, and assign it to the hidden planId field:

```
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#form1").submit(function() {
                            $('#planId').val($("input:submit").data());
                        });
                    });
```

I've tried different variations, like data('planId') and some other things, but I can't seem to get the planId out of the submit button the user pressed so I can pass it back to the server.

And if there is a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.  I thought about wrapping each green box in an a link, and using the link to call the form submit.  I'm not sure what benefit that is though.

Comment: I think best option would be **wrapping each green box in an a link, and using the link to call the form submit** as you mentioned.

Comment: Couldn't you give all the buttons a similar class name then attach a click event that submits the form then you should be able to access what ever data you need to in relation to the button.

Comment: what is the code of your form

Comment: I added the form code.  It was in the post but hidden because I didn't set it as code.